# Is value of variable always negative in case of overflow

Tags: c++, c, integer-overflow

It tried to solve this problem, given `N,K amd M`, find maximum integer `T` such that `N*(K^T) <= M`. `N,K and M` can be the values to `10^18`. So `long long` is sufficient.
I tried to solve it using iteration on T

```
int T = 0;
long long Kpow = 1;
while(1)
{
  long long prod = N*Kpow;
  if(prod > M)
    break;
  T++;
  Kpow = Kpow*K;
}
```

But since `N*Kpow` may go out of range of `long long`, there is need to handle the product using some big integer. But I found some other code which smartly handles this case

```
long long prod = N*Kpow;
if(prod < 0)
  break;
```

Even I have seen always, that in **overflow**, the value of variable becomes **negative**. Is it always the case or sometimes even positive values also occur in overflow case?

Comment: "If during the evaluation of an expression, the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of
representable values for its type, the behavior is undefined."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the point of view of the language, the behaviour of signed integer overflow is **undefined**. Which means anythign could happen - it can be negative, it can be unchanged, the program can crash or it can order pizza online.

What will most likely happen in practice depends on the processor architecture on which you're running - so you'd have to consult the platform specs to know.

But I'd guess you can't guarantee overflow to be negative. As a contrived example:

```
signed char c = 127;
c += 255;
std::cout << (int)c << '\n';
```

This happens to [print `126`](http://ideone.com/pmuqyD) on x86. But again, it could actually do anything.

Comment: Overflow behaviour can also change with optimisation level in the compiler since the compiler is allowed to assume that overflow won't happen in a correct program and optimise accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

No.  The value of variable is *not* always negative in case of overflow.

With signed integers, C11dr **§3.7.1 3 undefined behavior** "An example of undefined behavior is the behavior on integer overflow." so there is no test to do *after* overflow that is certain to work across compilers and platforms.

Detect potential overflow *before* it can happen.

```
int T = 0;
long long Kpow = 1;
long long Kpow_Max = LLONG_MAX/K;
long long prod_Max = LLONG_MAX/N;

while(1)
{
  if (Kpow > prod_Max) Handle_Overflow();
  long long prod = N*Kpow;
  if(prod > M)
    break;
  T++;
  if (Kpow > Kpow_Max) Handle_Overflow();
  Kpow = Kpow*K;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Couldn't this problem be converted to K^T <= (M + N - 1) / N?

As far as overflow detection goes, normally addition and subtraction are performed as if the numbers were unsigned, with the overflow bit set based on signed math, and the carry / borrow bit set based on unsigned math. For multiplication, the low order of the result is the same for signed or unsigned multiply (this is why the ARM cpu only has a signed / unsigned multiply for 64 bit results from 32 bit operands). Overflow occurs if the product is too large to fit in the register that receives the product, like a 32 bit multiply that results in a 39 bit product, that is supposed to go into a 32 bit register. For divide, overflow can occur if the divisor is zero or if the quotient is too large to fit in the register that receives the quotient, for example a 64 bit dividend divided by a 32 bit divisor, resulting in a 40 bit quotient. For multiply and divide, it doesn't matter if the operands are signed or not, only if the size of the result will fit in the register that receives the result.

Comment: This is a question, not an answer.

Comment: It's a possible solution to the problem faced in the original post.

Answer (score -4):

Just as in any other situation with signed integers of any length...overflow makes the number negative if and only if the specific bit which is overflowed into the sign bit is on.

Meaning if the result of your arithmetic would give you an overflow which, if you were to double the length of your variable word, would leave your current sign bit as off, you could quite possibly come up with an erroneous result which is positive.

Comment: not actually true. The behaviour of signed integer overflow is undefined. There are systems (e.g. dps) where overflow results in the max value.

Comment: -1 _'overflow makes the number negative'_ That's utterly wrong! Overflow is undefined behavior. It could do anything ...